# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=15.0.0.0,

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, .net-assembly, gac, sharepoint-2019

i am getting below error in SharePoint 2019 site.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

i have added the assembly in GAC and did changes in web.config as well. Still same issue even after IISRESET and server reboot. Please help.

i have followed steps mentioned in below URL as well

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-2019-could-not-load-file-microsoft-office-excel-webui/m-p/508744/highlight/false#M29692

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Remove the web parts and re-insert the web parts.
2. Add the following entry to the assemblyBinding section of the web.config file:

More reference:

Web part controls don't work after sites are migrated to SharePoint 2016.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4013911/some-web-parts-do-not-work-after-the-sites-is-migrated-to-sharepoint